# XAML - binding to Path=TimeSpan.TotalMinutes

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I need to bind TextBlock.Text with a property named SumOfPeriods of the type TimeSpan in following way:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0:D1} h {1:D1} min ({2:D1} min)">
            <Binding Path="SumOfPeriods.Hours" />
            <Binding Path="SumOfPeriods.Minutes" />
            <Binding Path="SumOfPeriods.TotalMinutes" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

... but it does not work. The content is not displayed.
When I remove binding to TotalMinutes it works and content is displayed:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0:D1} h {1:D1} min">
            <Binding Path="SumOfPeriods.Hours" />
            <Binding Path="SumOfPeriods.Minutes" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TotalMinutes` is a `Double`, but the [`D` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#DFormatString) is only supported for integral types such as `Int32`. A format string such as `{}{0:D1} h {1:D1} min ({2} min)` should work.

Answer (score 0):

A converter could solve your problem:

```cs
public class PeriodConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var timeSpan = (TimeSpan)value;

        // add your format here
        var text = string.Format("", timeSpan);

        return text;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

Add the converter to your resources:

```xml
<FrameworkElement.Resources>
    <converters:PeriodConverter x:Key="periodConverter" />
</FrameworkElement.Resources>
```

Update the binding of your TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding Path=SumOfPeriods, Converter={StaticResource periodConverter}} />
```